# Sending DStream's rdds in socket only works after closing the application

Tags: sockets, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying a Spark Streaming setup where the application receives a text (line), does the word count on it and then send the results back to the server.

Here's what I'm trying right now:

```
sc = SparkContext('local[4]', 'StreamTest')
sc.setLogLevel('WARN')
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

lines = ssc.socketTextStream('localhost', 9999)
words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split())

pairs = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
word_counts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)

def save_rdd(time, rdd):
    if rdd.isEmpty():
        return

    print('1')
    con = socket.socket()
    con.connect(('localhost', 9999))
    con.send('test')
    con.close()
    print('2')
    # rdd.saveAsTextFile('ws' + time.strftime('%s'))

word_counts.foreachRDD(save_rdd)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I start a server using `nc -lk 9999` and I send a random sentence expecting a `'test'` string back.

The problem is that I think it does work (the `'1'` and `'2'` gets printed) but I can't see the `'test'` on the server. The weird thing is that when I end the application I can then see it on the server.

Why does this happen? Is it even possible to send DStream results in a socket? I am trying to do some real time sentiment analysis and I want to report to my server.

Comment: This code doesn't look right. As far as I can tell it should just fail with connection refused exception, as there is no active socket, to which receiver would connect.

Comment: If i take the save_rdd part and execute it alone it works with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to flush the data after you send it,below is a java code which does it

```
 Socket s=new Socket("localhost",6666);  
 DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
 dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");  
 dout.flush();  
 dout.close();  
 s.close();
```